# How to transpose rows into columns in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Sorry for misleading question but I don't know hot to name my issue.

My db<>fiidle is [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=429df787efa54de898721eae622f5e0a).

I have a table with defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE shift (
     worker_name VARCHAR(25), 
     log_time DATETIME, 
     in_out VARCHAR(3)
);
```

It contains the following data:

```
INSERT INTO shift VALUES ('User 1', '2018-05-14 07:24:40.000', 'IN');
INSERT INTO shift VALUES ('User 2', '2018-05-14 11:55:29.000', 'IN');
INSERT INTO shift VALUES ('User 3', '2018-05-14 14:03:26.000', 'IN');
INSERT INTO shift VALUES ('User 1', '2018-05-14 14:05:08.000', 'Out');
INSERT INTO shift VALUES ('User 3', '2018-05-14 20:08:30.000', 'Out');
INSERT INTO shift VALUES ('User 2', '2018-05-14 20:08:36.000', 'Out');
INSERT INTO shift VALUES ('User 4', '2018-05-14 20:09:14.000', 'Out');
```

And as a result I would like to get:

```
worker_name | IN                  | OUT
:---------- | :------------------ | :------------------
User 1      | 14/05/2018 07:24:40 | 14/05/2018 14:05:08   
User 2      | 14/05/2018 11:55:29 | 14/05/2018 20:08:36   
User 3      | 14/05/2018 14:03:26 | 14/05/2018 20:08:30     
User 4      |      ----------     | 14/05/2018 20:09:14
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Can a worker has more than one IN or one OUT?

Comment: no, a worker has only one IN and one OUT, if exists. It can be there is only IN, or OUT. But cannot have more than one.

Comment: What happens if there is only one IN or one OUT?

Comment: For example in 'User 4': there should be something like '---'

Comment: A worker has only 1 IN and 1 OUT? Or 1 IN and 1 OUT per day?

Comment: Maybe the others answers are the way to go if your situation, but don't forget that you work into a team. I propose more general and error prone solutions: 1 Ask programmers to do their job and provide queries adapted to your data model. 2 Ask your analyst to change the data model to adapt to real use cases modelling.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an example of pivoting:

```
select worker_name, max(_in) as _in, max(_out) as _out 
from (
    select worker_name
         , case when in_out = 'IN' then log_time end as _in
         , case when in_out = 'OUT' then log_time end as _out 
    from shift
) as t 
group by worker_name;
```

The idea is to map `log_time` to `_in` when `in_out = 'IN'`, ditto for `_out`. In the outer `select` an aggregate function is used to filter out nulls. Try running the inner `select` first to get an idea of what is happening.

In general, the presentation of data is better handled by the application layer. So I would suggest reading the table as is, and let the presentation of the data be handled by the application.

Answer (score 3):

This appears to create the desired result in your db<>fiddle.

```
WITH sIN(Ctr, worker_name, log_time)
AS (
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY worker_name ORDER BY log_time) AS     Ctr, worker_name, log_time
 FROM shift
 WHERE in_out = 'IN'
 ),sOUT(Ctr, worker_name, log_time)
AS (
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY worker_name ORDER BY log_time) AS Ctr, worker_name, log_time
 FROM shift
 WHERE in_out = 'Out'
 )
  SELECT ISNULL(sIN.worker_name, sOUT.worker_name) AS worker_name,
    ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),sIN.log_time,120),'-----') AS [In],
    ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),sOUT.log_time,120),'-----') AS [Out]
 FROM sIN FULL OUTER JOIN sOUT
   ON sIN.worker_name = sOUT.worker_name AND sIN.Ctr = sOUT.Ctr
 ORDER BY 1,2,3
```

However, there's nothing preventing IN from being after OUT on the resultset. A more thorough solution could solve that, but I leave it as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Hmm, just realized OP commented "a worker has only one IN and one OUT" so this solution is probably overkill. I was thinking each worker had multiple INs and OUTs, like timekeeping over a week or month.

Answer (score 2):

This should get you started:

```
    select s1.worker_name, s1.in_out as in, s2.in_out as out
    from shift s1
    left join shift s2 on s1.worker_name = s2.worker_name 
    and cast(s1.log_time as date) = cast(s2.log_time as date)
    where s1.In_out = 'IN'
    and isnull(s2.in_out,'Out') = 'Out'
```

Maybe you want a full outer join instead of a left, to make it look exactly like your desired output. I'd try it with both and see which you prefer.

As a few have mentioned, without the isnull fuction, you may as well have inner joined.

There are a few other places you can apply isnull() to potentially change the output, too. In the join, for example.

Comment: You miss workers that log in and out on different dates. Since there are only 1 in, and 1 out, you can remove the date predicate from the join. You will still miss workers with only 1 in_out.

Comment: in this example, yea. It's a bit weird to me to have a table that doesn't store the ins and outs for all time, though.

Comment: if a worker forgets to log in or out, so there is one 'in/out' missing, for that i woul like to have ' ---- ' for missing 'in/out' instead of missing row

Comment: ahh, then you'll want an isnull(In,'----')

Comment: None of the log_time match in the data provided.  The where would break the left.

Comment: @paparazzo, yea, they don't match as datetimes, but if you cast them as dates, they will match up.

Comment: @James OK I missed that.  Where would still break the left.

Answer (score 2):

There is no constraint on that table to stop multiple `in` or `out`
Put a PK or unique constraint on worker_name, in_out

```
select s1.worker_name, sIn.in_out as in, sOut.in_out as out
  from shift sIn
  full outer join shift sOut 
    on sIn.worker_name = sOut.worker_name  
   and sIn.In_out  = 'IN'
   and sOut.in_out = 'Out' 
 order by s1.worker_name, sIn.in_out, sOut.in_out
```